# android textureVIew Flicking

Tags: android, android-textureview

iam using textureView for  draw json data like waveform its draw perfect but i want to update the background of the draw `onTouch` On `ACTION_MOVE` but i faced and problem its made my drawing  Flicking  this an gif image for the result of course the problem while move View with finger

[image]

and this the code was update the background color

```
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

  Canvas canvasX = null;
            try {
                canvasX = surface.lockCanvas(null);

                synchronized (surface) {
                    canvas.save();
                    mPaint2.setColor(Color.RED);
                    mPaint2.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
                    canvasX.drawRect(0, 0, event.getRawX() + dX, canvasX.getHeight(),mPaint2);


                    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
                    canvasX.drawRect(event.getRawX() + dX, 0, canvasX.getWidth(), canvasX.getHeight(),mPaint);


                    canvas.restore();
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvasX != null) {

                    surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvasX);
                }
            }







            this.animate()
                    .x(event.getRawX() + dX)

                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();

            break;
```

any one have an idea about what happen here and how can i solve it

Comment: `this.animate().x(event.getRawX() + dX).setDuration(0)` - zero duration in animation? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink this just move the View thats contain `textureView`